# Facebook JS SDK share count not increasing

Tags: facebook, zend-framework, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-sharer

I did my research and found no blog posts about this problem.

Basically I'm creating a Facebook share button for my Zend app using the feed dialog method.

My html in view.phtml

```
<div id="fb_share">Share</div> 
    <?= $this->share->share_count; ?>
    <p id='msg'></p>
```

My facebook.js that handles events

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#fb_share').click(function() {
        link = window.location.href;
        data = {
            method: 'feed',
            link: link,
            name: $('.thesis').html(),
            caption: $('.author').html(),
            description: $('.body').html()
        };
        postToFeed(data);
    });
});

function postToFeed(data) {

  // calling the API ...
  var obj = {
    method: data['method'],
    link: data['link'],
    picture: data['picture'],
    name: data['name'],
    caption: data['caption'],
    description: data['description']
  };

  function callback(response) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
  }

  FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

Code snippet relevant to facebook in my viewAction php

```
            $uri = $this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();

            $fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
            $fql .= "total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM ";
            $fql .= "link_stat WHERE url = '$uri'";

            $apifql="https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=".urlencode($fql);
            $json=file_get_contents($apifql);
            $fbshare = json_decode($json);
            $share = $fbshare[0];
            //echo($share->share_count);
            $this->view->share = $share;
            $this->view->uri = $uri;
```

So sharing works, but the share_count is not increasing every time I share the page.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The share count increases when I use the regular method of using <a name="fb_share">

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug on Facebook's side.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/458147890872559

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
FB.ui({
            display: 'popup',
            method: 'stream.share',
            href: href
        }
```

It will increase the count.